# Replace or Merge in R?

Tags: r, replace, merge

I would like to replace the rows in one data frame with rows from another data frame by the ID and Product. I have tried using merge, but I am only left with the rows that were merged. Is there a way to merge/replace so that my data set will look like the one below?

```
library(data.table)
DF <- as.data.table(list(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5), Product = c('Y', 'W', 'N', 'Z', 'A'), Type = c(2, 4, 5, 7, 4)))

DF
ID   Product Type
1       Y     2
2       W     4
3       N     5
4       Z     7
5       A     4
```

and

```
DF2 <- as.data.table(list(ID = c(1,2,3), Product = c('Y','W','N'), Category = c(1, 1, 5)))

DF2
ID   Product Category
1       Y     1
2       W     1
3       N     5
```

Which i would like to look like:

```
ID   Product Type Category 
1       Y     2      1
2       W     4      1
3       N     5      5 
4       Z     7      NA
5       A     4      NA
```

My code:

```
merge(DF, DF2, by=c('ID', 'Product'))
```

Comment: Your `DF` and `DF2` weren't properly defined above. A bunch of your `Product` items didn't have quotes so `R` is looking for variables with those names. Have addressed this in my answer

Comment: @Dan - fixed in an edit now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead

```
library(data.table)
DF <- as.data.table(list(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5), Product = c('Y', 'W', 'N', 'Z', 'A'), Type = c(2, 4, 5, 7, 4)))
DF2 <- as.data.table(list(ID = c(1,2,3), Product = c('Y', 'W', 'N'), Category = c(1, 1, 5)))

merge(DF, DF2, by=c("ID","Product"), all.x=TRUE)
```

Comment: Or using the data.table specific syntax - `DF2[DF, on=c("ID","Product"), nomatch=NA]`